# html5 way to make input type="number" only accept numbers?

Tags: html, html-input

I have `<input type="number">` and enter into the text field non-numeric characters just fine. Sure, I could use javascript to enforce this "number-only" requirement but is there an HTML5 way to do it in the HTML itself?

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/dqev8qmz/

(I'm using Google Chrome)

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no pure HTML way to achieve that. You will need javascript if you want to prevent the user from typing arbitrary characters. HTML5 provides the `pattern` attribute which will prevent the form from submitting if the user entered invalid value:

```
<form>
    <input type="number" pattern="\d+" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```